# Indicar la codificación de textos en Java

Tags: java, codificación

Cuando trabajo con Streams encuentro el problema de que no soy capaz de mostrar los caracteres especiales como las letras con tilde. Al crear el InputStreamReader indico su codificación pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente. Por ejemplo:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping", "8.8.8.8");
    Process p = pb.start();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (p.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    String linea;

    while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(linea);
    }
```

Se puede ver el error en las últimas líneas:
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    M�nimo = 23ms, M�ximo = 28ms, Media = 24ms

Comment: El resultado lo ves en la consola del IDE o donde?

Comment: Sí, en la consola del IDE o ejecutando la aplicación desde línea de comandos.

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar la codificación de lo que te llega a ISO-8859-1, por ejemplo?

Comment: Sí pero con el mismo resultado. Probé a escribir "UTF-8" y "UTF8" pero sigue sin funcionar.